# How to trigger multiple videos with ar.js

Tags: aframe, ar.js, queryselector

FINAL UPDATE 9/13/2019 11:50pm :
This code works with several custom markers, however the markers cannot be too similar. My previous custom markers were all stars with mild differences, and I think this was tripping it up somehow. But with newer, more unique markers, it works.

For some reason, though, this did not affect the result when using the "separate components" method.

---

Updated: 9/13/2019 : The below code works with hiro and kanji preset markers and one custom marker. However, when I add *multiple* custom markers, the videos freeze on the extra markers. I would like each marker to trigger unique videos (some videos will be re-used in several markers). In my current code, I just have them all triggering both videos. *How can I get this code to work with multiple custom markers?

```
<!-- A-FRAME -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe- 
ar.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe- 
extras/v4.1.2/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif- 
shader/master/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js"></script> 

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script> 

<!-- vidhandler component -->
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('vidhandler', {
schema: {
  target: {type: 'string'}
},
init: function() {
    this.videoNodes = document.querySelectorAll(this.data.target)
},
tick: function() {
    if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
        if (!this.toggle) {
            this.toggle = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
                this.videoNodes[i].play();
            } 
        }
    } else {
        if (this.toggle) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
            this.videoNodes[i].pause();
          }
          this.toggle = false;
        }
    }
}
});
</script>

<!-- assets for vidhandler -->
<a-assets >
    <video crossOrigin="Anonymous" Id="vid" 
loop="true"src="assets\textures\alpha.webm">
    </video>
    <video crossOrigin="Anonymous" Id="videonew" loop="true" src="assets\textures\VideoNew.mp4">
    </video>     
</a-assets>

 <!-- marker1: hollywood star 1 -->
 <a-marker  vidhandler="target: #vid, #videonew" type='pattern' url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/merowell/custom-markers-with-video/master/aframe/examples/assets/hollywood-stars/patt/pattern-hollywood-star1.patt'>
    <!-- add transparent video (.webm) -->
    <a-plane  position='0 .3 0' width='3' height='2' rotation="-90 0 0" material='transparent:true;alphaTest:0;src:#vid'></a-plane>

    <!-- add non transparent video (.mp4) -->
    <a-plane  position='0 .2 0' width='1.5' height='1.5' rotation="-90 0 0" material='src:#videonew'></a-plane>
</a-marker>


<!-- marker2: hollywood star 2 -->
<a-marker  vidhandler="target: #vid, #videonew" type='pattern' url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/merowell/custom-markers-with-video/master/aframe/examples/assets/hollywood-stars/patt/pattern-hollywood-star2.patt'>
     <!-- add transparent video (.webm) -->
    <a-plane  position='0 .3 0' width='3' height='2' rotation="-90 0 0" material='transparent:true;alphaTest:0;src:#vid'></a-plane>

    <!-- add non transparent video (.mp4) -->
    <a-plane  position='0 .2 0' width='1.5' height='1.5' rotation="-90 0 0" material='src:#videonew'></a-plane>
</a-marker>
```

---

Updated 9-12-19 : how to play separate videos with separate markers, with option to re-use certain videos? With the following code, the videos display as a static image:

```
<!-- vidhandler component -->
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('vidHandler', {
// define a variable in which we will keep the video element
schema: {
 targets: {type: "string"}
},
 init: function() {
    this.toggle = false;
    this.vidNodes = document.querySelectorAll(this.data.targets);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
          this.vidNodes[i].pause();
    }
},
tick: function() {
    if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
        if (!this.toggle) {
            this.toggle = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
              this.vidNodes[i].play();
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.toggle = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
          this.vidNodes[i].pause();
        }
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Original question:

Please forgive me as I am very new to this....

I'm using ar.js with aframe to create a webAR experience. I'm using two different markers to trigger two different videos.

How do I make the Aframe.register component trigger both of my videos separately? The two videos are listed as assets, with the following IDs: #vid #videonew

the expected results are for the two markers to display a unique video that loops, whether both markers are shown to the webcam, or if it's just one of the markers. But the actual result is the videos only play if both markers are shown to the webcam. Otherwise, individually, the videos display as a static image.

```
<!-- Video Player -->
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('vidhandler', {
init: function() {
    this.toggle = false;
    this.vidNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#vid, #videonew");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
          this.vidNodes[i].pause();
    }
},
tick: function() {
    if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
        if (!this.toggle) {
            this.toggle = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
              this.vidNodes[i].play();
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.toggle = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.vidNodes.length; i++) {
          this.vidNodes[i].pause();
        }
    }
}
});
</script>
```

```
<a-assets >
    <video crossOrigin="Anonymous" preload="auto"  Id="vid" loop="true"   webkit-playsinline playsinline controls>
       <source  type="video/webm"  src="assets\textures\alpha.webm">
       <h3>Error : Your browser does not support.</h3>
      <!-- FOR NOTMAL VIDEO YOU CAN USE MP4 or WEBM BUT FOR ALPHA VIDEO YOU NEED TO USE .WEBM FORMAT-->
    </video>

     <video crossOrigin="Anonymous" preload="auto"  Id="videonew" loop="true"   webkit-playsinline playsinline controls>
       <source  type="video/webm"  src="assets\textures\VideoNew.mp4">
       <h3>Error : Your browser does not support.</h3>
      <!-- FOR NOTMAL VIDEO YOU CAN USE MP4 or WEBM BUT FOR ALPHA VIDEO YOU NEED TO USE .WEBM FORMAT-->
    </video>
</a-assets>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. One marker triggers two videos

[document.querySelectorAll(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a container (NodeList) with the matching elements. 
To call `.play()` on each video, you need to [iterate through the container](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) and call it on each element.

---

Each `this.vid.play()`, and `this.vid.pause()` needs to be replaced with:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.vid.length; i++) {
    this.vid[i].play() // or this.vid[i].pause()
}
```

Also it wouldn't hurt to rename it to `this.videoNodes` :)

---

Check out in [this](https://stack-57863016.glitch.me/) glitch how you can do triggering two videos with aframe, and ar.js

### 2. Two markers, each with a unique video

No need to duplicate the component for each marker, you only need a modification which will allow providing the video to the component. That way you can use the same component, for different video elements. We can achieve that with the components [schema](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-properties-with-the-schema).

**js** - using the element from the schema

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('vidHandler', {
  // define a variable in which we will keep the video element
  schema: {
     video: {type: 'selector'},
  },
  init: function() {
     // use the video from the schema
     this.video = this.data.video
     this.video.pause()
  },
  tick: function() {
    if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
      if (!this.toggle) {
        this.toggle = true;
        this.video.play()
      }
     } else {
      this.toggle = false;
      this.video.pause()
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML** - providing the element to the component

```
<a-assets>
   <video id="one">
   <video id="two">
</a-assets>
<a-marker preset="hiro" vidhandler="video: #one">
    <a-box material='src: #one'></a-box>
</a-marker>
<a-marker preset="kanji" vidhandler="video: #two">
    <a-box material='src: #two'></a-box>
</a-marker>
```

### 3. Two markers trigger any number of videos

By now we are providing a selector to the component, but we can also provide a string to feed the `document.querySelectorAll()` method:

```
// <a-marker videohandler="videos: #one, #two">
// videohandler insides:
schema: {
  videos: {type: 'string'}
},
init: function() {
    this.videoNodes = document.querySelectorAll(this.data.target)
},
// the rest like in the first case
```

Although there are some issues here.

- Make sure you pause the video only once the marker is lost. Otherwise one component will pause the video on each tick.
- If you want to play the video from the beginning on another marker, you'd need to cache the timestamp once the marker is lost.

Working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-57863016?path=arjstwoseparate.html:5:4).

Comment: I corrected the component with your suggestions, but I still get the same result. Only #vid works, while #videonew is just a static image. 

I need to research how to iterate through the container like you said-- I don't really know what that means. Sorry I'm such a noob! 

Outside of literally just replacing "this.vid.play/pause()" with "for (let i = 0; i < this.vid.length; i++) {this.vid[i].play() // or this.vid[i].pause()}".... was there something else I was supposed to do?

Comment: I can't do an ar.js example atm (will do later), but check [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-57863016?path=index.html:22:121) out. Pressing space plays the videos, releasing pauses them.

Comment: Piotr, I'm sorry for all the comments, I got it working just fine, also with the transparency. But for whatever reason it only works for one marker. I can put two videos in one marker and they both work. But I want two markers with two separate videos.

Comment: your adjusted code works great for playing separate videos with two different markers. But if I wanted to say have hiro play #one, and kanji play #one and #two, would I then need to make separate components?

Comment: @merowell like now ? Is the anwser clear at all with all this information ?

Comment: the videos now show up as a white plane. I updated my original post with the code I have now for the vidhandler component. Does it look right to you?

Comment: @merowell i've added an update, let me know if it is what you're looking for

Comment: thank you so much! I appreciate your patience very much-- I still have a lot to learn. You rule! I imagine your thoughtful answers will help others who took the "you can make webAR with 10 lines of HTML" bait. haha :)

Comment: Ahhh @piotr I thought it was working smoothly, but it seems that when I remove the first marker from the webcam, the next marker freezes on the video where it left off. Maybe adding the timestamp thing would help? Forcing it to play from the beginning. How might I do that? Or perhaps you have another idea of what could be causing this.

Comment: I'm posting my most updated code. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using transparent videos, thus Aframe v 0.8? Because your example runs flawlessly, but when I apply it with my assets, the videos freeze.

Comment: okay, after troubleshooting, I've figured out that when I replace my custom markers with the preset hiro/kanji markers, it works. Any thoughts on why it wouldn't work with the custom markers?

Comment: Alrighty @piotr, I figured out that my custom markers looked too similar and that's why multiple custom markers was tripping it up. Again thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Piotr answered this question and provided a great example with this glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-57863016?path=arjs.html:3:0

Thank you! Also, where I was failing, was I wasn't including 'vidhandler' in the a-marker section.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I got it--- In order to get separate videos to play with separate markers, I needed to create a second component. Each marker needs a unique component handler, at least, this is how I got it working.

Comment: No need in duplicating the component, check out my updated anwser