# AR.js and A-Frame example

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I am looking for an example of how to trigger images and then play a video.

It is a very simple use case: In a newspaper, videos can be watched regarding the articles, if the image is an marker.

All samples I have seen loads a 3D model or something like that. Do I need a layer in which the video plays?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472989/video-playback-in-augmented-reality-on-detecting-marker-using-a-frames), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363819/how-to-load-or-play-video-playback-when-the-marker-is-detected-hiro), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863016/how-to-trigger-multiple-videos-with-ar-js). Try it out, if you find it incomplete, or outdated feel free to comment or ask a more specific question

Comment: Are you trying to use a marker or an image tracker?

Comment: Not really, not so much fancy. A video should play not in a cube, but in a layer above the image. Similar to [this](https://www.wikitude.com/blog-image-recognition-and-tracking-augmented-reality-use-cases-and-how-to/) in section "Cloud Recognition".